# Can DynamoDB batch delete items that have a specific partition key?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, nosql

I am writing an iOS app using AWS DynamoDB. I have a table of notes and each note is associated with a user ID as global secondary index partition key. Is it possible to batch delete all notes associated with a specific user ID?

Comment: can you share you table and index structure? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataFormat.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, this is your table...

`Notes Table: noteID (hash key), userID, [other attributes]
UserNotesGSI: userID (hash key), noteID (range key)`

... and you are asking if there is a way to delete all rows in the UserNotesGSI with the same userID.

This is not currently possible, given that you cannot write/delete items from a GSI at all. GSIs are auto-synchronized for you by DynamoDB, based on changes that you make to the main table (`Notes`). More details [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html).

If you look at the [BatchWriteItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) and [DeleteItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html) methods, you'll notice that you can only specify the table that you want to update/remove items from and not the index, as you can with the [Query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) method. This further backs up my answer.